# SpriteKit performance drop when frame rate set to 60hz but NOT when 120hz on iPhone 13

Tags: ios, performance, sprite-kit, frame-rate, ios15

I've updated my SpriteKit game to iOS 15 and, when testing on an iPhone 13 Pro, I've discovered frame rate has steadily dropped to around 55-56fps on this device:

[image: Can't make 60fps]

However, when I set `preferredFramesPerSecond` to 120 (and the respective Info.plist key to allow it), everything keeps up at 120fps, no problem:

[image: 120fps, no problem.]

So, clearly my update logic is executing well within the allotted time to maintain 60fps. Also, there's no issue maintaining 60fps on the simulator or my other test devices (iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone X, 1st gen. iPhone SE).

This one has me scratching my head. Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks!

**Edit #1:** Interestingly, I can reproduce the same behavior on my build just by limiting the frame rate in iOS’ Accessibility settings:

[image: Frame rate limit setting]

Comment: May be there no need to go to 120 fps if screen does only refresh at 60Hz

Comment: @PtitXav The issue occurs when targeting 60fps.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I haven't figured this one out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue for me. It looks like one of the Xcode or iOS updates took care of it. Not sure which.